# how i group do this mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, charts

i want to make charts system
and i think it must be like that

```
1 jan 2009  = 10 post
2 jan 2009  = 2 post
4 jan 2009  = 10 post
6 jan 2009  = 60 post
```

and i have `posts` table that has id,user_id,date
how i can select from `posts` to show it like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try ..

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`date`, '%e %M %Y') as `post_date`, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY `post_date`
```

More information to reference:

- [`DATE_FORMAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
- [Aggregate Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: its return me t colum and no any thing i want

Comment: its really great but when changed to FROM_UNIXTIME